# Fitting a polynomial to my data

Tags: fitting, polynomials

I have a following polynomial:

```
N*p1*x^(p2)*(1-x)^(p3)* (1+ p5*x^(p4) + p6*x) = f(x).
```

where `N` is a constant say `N = 10`.

I have values for f(x) for several x.

```
     x            f(x)
1.0000*10^-07 1.4013*10^+01
1.1767*10^-07 1.3689*10^+01
1.3846*10^-07 1.3372*10^+01
1.6293*10^-07 1.3063*10^+01
1.9171*10^-07 1.2761*10^+01
2.2559*10^-07 1.2466*10^+01
2.6545*10^-07 1.2178*10^+01
3.1235*10^-07 1.1896*10^+01
3.6754*10^-07 1.1621*10^+01
4.3248*10^-07 1.1352*10^+01
5.0890*10^-07 1.1090*10^+01
5.9882*10^-07 1.0833*10^+01
7.0462*10^-07 1.0583*10^+01
8.2912*10^-07 1.0338*10^+01
9.7562*10^-07 1.0099*10^+01
1.1480*10^-06 9.8775*10^+00
1.3509*10^-06 9.6558*10^+00
1.5895*10^-06 9.4310*10^+00
1.8704*10^-06 9.2031*10^+00
2.2009*10^-06 8.9727*10^+00
```

My question is:

1. Is there any function in mathematica which can do this? I tried `FindFit` but it did not succeed.
2. Is it possible to find the parameters `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`, `p6`?
3. What is the minimum number of data point needed to make such a fit?

Comment: Make sure you import the data as numbers (and not as strings). Use ToExpression to convert strings looking like numbers to actual numbers. Then use NonlinearModelFit. Note that N is not be used as a variable name. NonlinearModelFit[data2, 
 10*p1*x^(p2)*(1 - x)^(p3)*(1 + p5*x^(p4) + p6*x), {p1, p2, p3, p4, 
  p5, p6}, x]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but if this is your real data, you don't want to fit a polynomial.  Look at `ListLogLogPlot[data]` and you'll see a straight line.  No need for a high-order polynomial.

Comment: A piece of advice: don't use `N` as variable name. `N` is reserved for an important built-in function. Using it as a variable can shadow the function.

Comment: do you want `p2,p3,p4` to be restricted to integers? Otherwise its not a polynomial.

Comment: @ago No, all pi can take any values. Its a function I want to fit to these data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Import to import data from a file:

```
data1 = Import["C:\\Users\\Aravind\\Desktop\\data.txt", "Data"]
```

Convert strings to numbers:

```
data2 = ToExpression /@ data1

nfit = 
  NonlinearModelFit[data2, 10*p1*x^(p2)*(1 - x)^(p3)*(1 + p5*x^(p4) + p6*x), 
    {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}, x]

nfit["BestFitParameters"]

(* {p1 -> 0.0196938, p2 -> 0.128675, p3 -> 215205., p4 -> -0.261865, 
 p5 -> 8.38579, p6 -> 6.17042*10^7} *)

lp = ListPlot[data2]

plt = Plot[nfit[x], {x, data2[[1, 1]], data2[[-1, 1]]}, PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[lp, plt]
```

[image]